¿Recuperar posición de la terminal integrada de Visual Studio Code?
Moví la posición la terminal integrada de Visual Studio Code a la derecha de la ventana (v.1.93.1 en Linux) y no consigo que vuelva al lugar por defecto (parte inferior).
La terminal sólo esta "movida" en el proyecto que tenía abierto, en todos los demás conserva su posición original.
Revise el fichero .editorconfig del proyecto pero no hay ninguna línea relacionada.
En el fichero de configuración del editor "settings.json" añadí la línea: "terminal.integrated.position": "down",.
Aparece como una configuración inexistente y no tiene efecto.
Añadí también la línea: "terminal.integrated.defaultLocation": "editor", y probé también con el valor "view" (aparece con el valor "view" en el fichero "defaultSettings.json"). Nada.
En la terminal en el desplegable junto al botón + voy a "Configure Terminal Settings"
aparecen los parámetros de configuración de la terminal y como modificados:

Abriendo otra ventana del editor donde la terminal sigue en su sitio no aparece "Modified in Workspace":

Al clickar sobre "Workspace" se abre el fichero ".vscode/settings.json" dentro del proyecto, con este contenido:
{
    "terminal.explorerKind": "default",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultLocation": "editor",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash"
}

He comentado las líneas, cerrado y abierto el editor.
Sigo sin recuperar la terminal.

Haz clic derecho sobre el título del panel (donde están las fichas DEBUG CONSOLE | TERMINAL | PORTS etcétera) sobre una parte vacía, luego clic en Panel Position y Bottom.

O  en la paleta de comandos busca Move Panel To Bottom

La solución del primer comentario es buena, muchas gracias.
No me acordaba como la moví y ha sido una locura intentar restaurarla.
